# Reorder date and batch rename files on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have a large list of files (2,554 items), named like so

`[mm_dd_yyyy hh_mm_ss] uniquefilenamestring.mp4`

when sorting theses by name, the folder of course puts all the months together, rather than sorting by year, I need to run a PowerShell regex on the filenames but can't work out what I need to do

Ideally I'd like

`[yyyy_mm_dd hh_mm_ss] uniquefilenamestring.mp4`

I feel like it's simple enough but I just cant fathom it, originally the files also had a 9 digit number in front of the square brackets but I managed to use the below to fix that.

`get-childitem *.mp4 | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(9) }`

Comment: i would convert the date strings into date objects & then use each object to generate the new date string.

Comment: Are those square brackets actually part of the file names or did you add them in the post to emphasize the part thet needs to be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to swap the year with the month/day. With or without the brackets this should do the trick.

```
get-childitem -filter *.mp4 |
    rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '(\d{2}_\d{2})_(\d{4})','$2_$1'}
```